# Why does the Haskell compiler returns relocation truncation error on mips mips64el

Tags: haskell, memory, linker, ghc

I am working on a package (haskell-src-exts) that could not be built for the mips64el architecture for Debian and the log returned by the autobuilder ends like this:

```
[24 of 24] Compiling Language.Haskell.Exts (src/Language/Haskell/Exts.hs, dist-ghc/build/Language/Haskell/Exts.p_o )
dist-ghc/build/Language/Haskell/Exts/Annotated/Syntax.dyn_o: In function `c66jH_entry':
ghc_8.hc:(.text+0x10c): relocation truncated to fit: R_MIPS_GOT_DISP against `stg_ap_0_fast'

[...]

ghc_8.hc:(.text+0x884): relocation truncated to fit: R_MIPS_GOT_DISP against `base_GHCziNum_zp_entry'
ghc_8.hc:(.text+0x8e4): additional relocation overflows omitted from the output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/share/cdbs/1/class/hlibrary.mk:147: recipe for target 'build-ghc-stamp' failed
make: *** [build-ghc-stamp] Error 1
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build-arch gave error exit status 2
```

After searching the web about relocation, and R_MIPS_GOT_DISP it seems to me that the linker is having a problem with the linking.

Strangely enough it seems like a kind of error you would get for incorrectly assigning an address to an object or something. The problem is  I am pretty sure you cannot have that type of control over memory in Haskell, and certainly not over the linker.

As written on Haskell's website:

> The LANGUAGE pragma allows language extensions to be enabled in a portable way. It is the intention that all Haskell compilers support the LANGUAGE pragma with the same syntax, although not all extensions are supported by all compilers, of course. The LANGUAGE pragma should be used instead of OPTIONS_GHC, if possible.

So this may be a case where a LANGUAGE pragma is used and not supported by the mips GHC compiler. Here is the line from the Syntax.hs file containing one of the pragmas:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable, DeriveGeneric #-}
```

Note that the package could be built on many other (non-mips) architectures.

If this is all true, I am forced to conclude that there is a problem with the mips64el version of GHC and this is what causes this bug.

Any clues?
Thanks alot

Comment: It's a linker error. Has nothing to do with the pragmas. There is an optimization on this platform where small objects are treated differently from large objects. A table that stores these small objects gets overflown. Google *mips GOT truncated*. I don't know how to remedy this. Try adding `-optl -G4` (or 2 or 1) to the compiler flags. It may or may not help. If it doesn't you probably should file a bug against ghc.